# How can I deliver iOS app to tester that hasn't got a mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, itunes

I'm developing an iOS application (I have macbook) and I have an apple developer's account.

How can I deliver iPhone app to tester that hasn't got a mac?

---

Tester's phone is not jailbroken (I can't build deb)

Comment: you have to make a .ipa file for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can run itunes on a windows machine too.  But if they don't have a computer at all there is another option.  You can distribute it via a link.

Its really easy.  Prepare to do an adhoc distribution as usual and then click the "Enterprise Distribution" tick box.

Then add the URL to where the final .ipa will be.  I usualyl fill in the app name on the second line as well but never fill the rest in.

e.g

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/YourApp/YourApp.ipa
```

Then upload the created .plist and .ipa to the relevant URL so that the 2 files are available as:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/YourApp/YourApp.ipa
http://www.yourdomain.com/YourApp/YourApp.plist
```

Now finally create a simple HTML page and upload it to your site.

```
<http>
    <body>
        <c><font size="20"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.yourdomain.com/YourApp/YourApp.plist">Click here to install YourApp</a></font></c>
    </body>
</http>
```

Now send them a link to the above HTML page and they are good to install.

***Be warned***: You must have the tester's UDID in the adhoc distribution profile certificate or this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Are I need have enterprise account for do this?

Comment: @CAMOBAP: No you don't which is where the whole thing is very confusing.  It can be done with a normal developer account though.  I use it on a normal dev account and it is a huge bonus because it means my colleagues don't have to use the abomination that is iTunes ;)

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using the [Test Flight](https://testflightapp.com) service. It allows you to upload builds of your application and distribute then to testers via their website.

They have a great [help section to get you started](http://help.testflightapp.com).

**EDIT:** Oh, and it's free for the basic service.

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Couldn't recommend this more. I think it's worth mentioning that Test Flight has remote distribution, so you only need to send an email link to the person for them to download your app.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Include the users' `udid`s into your `adhoc` distribution profile
   certificate (same step as in `Goz`'s answer).
2. In `Xcode`, use the Archive function and sign the code with the `adhoc` profile
   certificate.
3. In Organizer, create the .ipa file for distribution.
4. Send the `.ipa` file to your users (i.e. via email).
5. Ask them to drag and drop the `.ipa` file into Applications section of `iTunes` for Windows and synchronize their devices.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Mac OS and Mac machine to develop them. You will need XCode installed on Mac OSX to code, run and test your application.

If you do not want to buy Mac you can install Mac OSX on PC referring this link thats called Hackintosh. This works fine on PC if you follow steps properly:

http://tonymacx86.blogspot.in/2011/07/xmove-multibeast-install-os-x-107-lion.html

If that's not a possible, you may consider inviting the person over physically or to do it virtually via ex. Teamviewer or any other remote desktop protocol.

Comment: I have Mac OS, but my tester haven't it

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient and time saving approach that I have used so far is Test Flight. The integration is seamlessly easy. You can share files with testers and it does not require you to have a system.

The main steps are

1)Download and integrate [Testflight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) after creating a valid account (Login required).

2) Integrate the SDK with iPhone application (Though it isn't mandatory if you only wish to distribute the application and not track its usage and reporting purpose).

3) Create you team and upload build on Portal.

4) Subsequently allow testers to have access to the permitted devices mentioned in provisioning profile.

You can manage Multiple teams and applications at a single place. Hope it helps.